# Encoding error with Sidekiq

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg, redis, sidekiq

Im following this tutorial https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-12-08-building-video-sharing-app-server-messaging-ruby/ on Building a Video Sharing App. Its a bit outdated and Ive already had to fix a view issues to get this far but Im pretty lost now with this latest issue. I believe its something to do with sidekiq. When I try uploading a video it seems to work and shows up on the database, but I get a "Video is still being encoded." message.

This is the log:

```
2017-03-13T22:00:14.729Z 11109 TID-ova30dq94 WebmVideoEncoder JID-540aa74110e63e334a712719 INFO: fail: 0.122 sec
2017-03-13T22:00:14.730Z 11109 TID-ova30dq94 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"WebmVideoEncoder","args":[3],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"540aa74110e63e334a712719","created_at":1489441065.533313,"enqueued_at":1489442414.60714,"error_message":"exception class/object expected","error_class":"TypeError","failed_at":1489441065.541595,"retry_count":6,"retried_at":1489442414.7293491},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"WebmVideoEncoder\",\"args\":[3],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"540aa74110e63e334a712719\",\"created_at\":1489441065.533313,\"enqueued_at\":1489442414.60714,\"error_message\":\"exception class/object expected\",\"error_class\":\"TypeError\",\"failed_at\":1489441065.541595,\"retry_count\":5,\"retried_at\":1489441667.7081149}"}
2017-03-13T22:00:14.730Z 11109 TID-ova30dq94 WARN: TypeError: exception class/object expected
2017-03-13T22:00:14.730Z 11109 TID-ova30dq94 WARN: /Users/David/rubyProjects/videouploader/videouploader/app/workers/webm_video_encoder.rb:14:in `raise'
/Users/David/rubyProjects/videouploader/videouploader/app/workers/webm_video_encoder.rb:14:in `perform'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:158:in `execute_job'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:138:in `block (4 levels) in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq.rb:36:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in `block (3 levels) in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/sidetiq-7bec4084165f/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in `with_context'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:174:in `stats'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:106:in `block in call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:68:in `block in wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:67:in `wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:105:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:26:in `block in safe_thread'
2017-03-13T22:00:50.877Z 11109 TID-ova3gyd4k ThumbnailCutter JID-d0c693e39e06c2cccdec7d33 INFO: start
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `ffmpeg -i /Users/David/rubyProjects/videouploader/videouploader/public/system/videos/video_files/000/000/002/original/Heart_of_Gold_-_Neil_Young_cover_with_harmonica.1_(1).mp4 -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 /tmp/1489442450881632.png'
2017-03-13T22:00:50.902Z 11109 TID-ova3gyd4k ThumbnailCutter JID-d0c693e39e06c2cccdec7d33 INFO: fail: 0.025 sec
2017-03-13T22:00:50.903Z 11109 TID-ova3gyd4k WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"ThumbnailCutter","args":[2],"retry":true,"queue":"default","jid":"d0c693e39e06c2cccdec7d33","created_at":1489437193.246615,"enqueued_at":1489442450.8759801,"error_message":"exception class/object expected","error_class":"TypeError","failed_at":1489437193.254677,"retry_count":7,"retried_at":1489442450.901133},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"ThumbnailCutter\",\"args\":[2],\"retry\":true,\"queue\":\"default\",\"jid\":\"d0c693e39e06c2cccdec7d33\",\"created_at\":1489437193.246615,\"enqueued_at\":1489442450.8759801,\"error_message\":\"exception class/object expected\",\"error_class\":\"TypeError\",\"failed_at\":1489437193.254677,\"retry_count\":6,\"retried_at\":1489441044.6660218}"}
2017-03-13T22:00:50.903Z 11109 TID-ova3gyd4k WARN: TypeError: exception class/object expected
2017-03-13T22:00:50.903Z 11109 TID-ova3gyd4k WARN: /Users/David/rubyProjects/videouploader/videouploader/app/workers/thumbnail_cutter.rb:13:in `raise'
/Users/David/rubyProjects/videouploader/videouploader/app/workers/thumbnail_cutter.rb:13:in `perform'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:158:in `execute_job'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:138:in `block (4 levels) in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq.rb:36:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in `block (3 levels) in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bundler/gems/sidetiq-7bec4084165f/lib/sidetiq/middleware/history.rb:8:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in `with_context'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:174:in `stats'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block in process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:106:in `block in call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:68:in `block in wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:85:in `wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:67:in `wrap'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/rails.rb:105:in `call'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `process'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
/Users/David/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:26:in `block in safe_thread'
```

thumbnail_cutter.rb

```
class ThumbnailCutter
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(video_id)
    video = Video.find(video_id)
    output = "/tmp/#{Time.now.getutc.to_f.to_s.delete('.')}.png"
    _command = `ffmpeg -i #{video.video_file.path} -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 #{output}`
    if $?.to_i == 0
      video.thumbnail = File.open(output, 'r')
      video.save
      FileUtils.rm(output)
    else
      raise $?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have a syntax error in thumbnail_cutter.rb

```
2017-03-13T22:00:50.877Z 11109 TID-ova3gyd4k ThumbnailCutter JID-d0c693e39e06c2cccdec7d33 INFO: start
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('

  # need to add double quotes for interpolation its failing on video.video_file.path 
  # I believe its because of the name of your file  '.1_(1).mp4' 
  # if this doesn't work I would try and change the file name so it doesnt include '.1_(1) and just .1.mp4 or .1_1.mp4 
  _command = `"ffmpeg -i #{video.video_file.path} -ss 00:00:01.000 -vframes 1 #{output}"`
```

Comment: I cant seem to find the syntax error. I added thunbnail_cutter.rb to my post. Would you mind taking a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
raise $?
```

is not legal Ruby code.